# How to compare matrix dimensions in a 1xN struct array

Tags: arrays, matlab, data-structures

I have a 1xN struct array with a field that stores a vector `v`. In general, N > 2.

I use the `arrayfun` function to check if those `v` vectors are the same for all of the N elements in the struct array:

```
if  all(arrayfun(@isequal,matrix.v))
```

The problem is I currently want to check if all the `v` vectors have the same size before calling the line above. I cannot use `arrayfun`, because it needs all the arguments to have the same dimensions.

When N = 2, there is no problem, because I can simply do something like

```
if length(matrix(1).v) == length(matrix(2).v)
```

However, for the general situation (N > 2), how can I make this dimension verification?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the sizes of your structure by using your own function as:

```
[nrows, ncols] = arrayfun(@(x) size(x.v), matrix)
```

Now you just need to make sure that `nrows` and `ncols` are the same number for all cases of `matrix.v` so you can just do

```
samesize=length(unique(nrows))==1 && length(unique(ncols))==1;
```

Comment: Thank you, but it does not work, as the elements of `matrix.v` have different sizes, so that `arrayfun` returns this error (for N = 2):

`Error using arrayfun
All of the input arguments must be of the same size and shape.
Previous inputs had size 36 in dimension 2. Input #3 has size 51.`

Answer (score 1):

An alternative, is to `try` and `catch` the error, since you are only expecting this error, this is not as good as Ander's answer, but it is an alternative:

```
try
   all(arrayfun(@isequal,matrix.v))
catch exception  %//Same as if it throws an error
   %//...your statements...%//
   %//you could do something like ans = 1 since anw will equal 0 if all(arrayfun(@isequal,matrix.v)) is true
end
```

For example:

```
value = {[1,2,3];
[10, 20, 30];
[100,200,300,400]};
s = struct('f',value);
try
   all(arrayfun(@isequal,s.f))
catch exception
   ans=1
end

>> ans = 1
```

BUT this does not care what the exception is, so if your code is broken by a different error, it would still continue giving a 1 for ans.One advantage is it only evaluate the arrayfun once :D so speedwise it is faster (I think?)